# Is there a way to disable Arrow Format Support with latest Snowflake JDBC driver

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using Snowflake JDBC driver version 3.11.1 we get below error on big-endian platforms.

We are observing an issue with latest Snowflake JDBC driver where even basic Select queries are failing with below exception. It used to work with earlier version 3.10.3. It seems issue with "Arrow" . Any plans of fixing this issue. Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Arrow only runs on LittleEndian systems. at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.io.netty.buffer.UnsafeDirectLittleEndian.(UnsafeDirectLittleEndian.java:65) at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.io.netty.buffer.UnsafeDirectLittleEndian.(UnsafeDirectLittleEndian.java:50) at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocatorL.(PooledByteBufAllocatorL.java:50) at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.arrow.memory.AllocationManager.(AllocationManager.java:53) snowflake-da

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to disable Arrow for Snowflake clients. I would suggest you to use an earlier version of the JDBC driver (e.g. 3.9.x) to workaround it for the moment and contact Snowflake Support to explore your options moving forward.

Comment: Thanks. I will check with Snowflake Support.

Comment: Problem is that earlier versions does not have Bouncy Castle upgrade. Lower bouncy castle has High security vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the following alter session commands using latest snowflake driver on AIX environment?

ALTER SESSION SET JDBC_QUERY_RESULT_FORMAT='JSON'

Reference: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/SAP-BW-Java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-for-Apache-arrow